# PJSIP how to get on_rx_notify to fire?

Tags: pjsip

I am using PJSIP's evsub methods to send out a SUBSCRIBE.   This is sent an UAC transaction.   The other side then sends an OK response and then a NOTIFY request.   This request is assumed to be an UAS transaction by the PJSIP Dialog and transaction code and doesn't match the UAC transaction which the evsub is looking changes on.   So, how do I get the on_rx_notify callback method to fire?

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore the question, it turned out it was working through all that, just that it was adding an id= to the event and the other side did not return it.  If anyone has other questions I've been all through the code and have a better understanding of it now.